# How can I monitor the progress of a XamlWriter.Save() operation?

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, xamlreader

I have a FlowDocument I want to save, and later load.

I think I can do this with XamlWriter.Save() and XamlReader.Load().

It works, but it takes *a long time*.  The time it takes is the time it takes, I guess, but to make the UI more simpatico, I'd like to present a progressbar showing the save progress.

But how can I monitor the progress of a `XamlWriter.Save()`?

One idea, for saving, is to create a thin wrapper class around the destination stream;  it can then track progress by counting how many bytes get sent through the Write() method. This will work but it's sort of an open-ended progress, since I don't have a way to figure % complete.

I suppose I could do something similar on the reading side.

anyone done this?  What's a good way to track progress of XamlWriter.Save() ?